# How to use Optional Parameter and Rest Parameter together in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to have a function definition which should contain both Optional and Rest Parameter. While invoking the function, am not getting desired output from the function. While invoking a function should I use some special keyword or something?

In the below function, the address is an optional parameter and names is a Rest Parameter. How can I invoke this function?

```
function Greet(age:number,address?:string,...names: string[]):void{
    console.log(age);
    console.log(address);
    console.log(names)
}

Greet(20,"Mathan","Maddy")
```

Here am passing parameters only to age and names. but the second value "Mathan" is getting considered for address in my function.

Comment: _"am not getting desired output from the function"_ What does this mean? What is the input you are providing it? Are you expecting the function to be able to accept `names` _without_ an `address`? If so, that's not going to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's my question. I had updated my question. Provided more clarity to it.

Comment: Think of this from the perspective of the JavaScript engine: how is it supposed to know that the `"Mathan"` in `Greet(20,"Mathan","Maddy")` is supposed to be a name and the `"90 Fake Street"` in `Greet(20,"90 Fake Street","Maddy")` is supposed to be an address? In both cases, all it knows is that it's being passed a number and two strings. It's not possible to use an optional parameter and a rest parameter in the way you're trying to do. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734509/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-in-typescript-while-omitting-some-other-optional?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I don't really see any way you could do it other than explicitly specify `undefined` for the optional value:

`Greet(20, undefined, 'Maddy')`

There isn't a way to infer whether the second parameter is the optional one, or the start of the rest ones.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, in this case, the address will be having undefined. Instead, I don't want to have any value to it.

Comment: If you don't pass any value, the value will also be `undefined`. Log the output if you call `Greet(20)`. That's what `undefined` means.

Comment: @Mathan `undefined` is as close to "no value" that you could ever get.