# How to call a method with an argument sometimes and sometimes no argument passed using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Sometimes, I want to pass a second argument to a function, but sometimes I don't pass the second argument.

Below is my method:

```
const updateStartEnd = (newEndDate: any, newStartDate: any) => {
    if (prevDate && newStartDate && newStartDate.isBefore(prevDate, 'd')) {
        setEndDate(newStartDate);
    } else {
        setEndDate(newEndDate);
    }
};
```

I call this function like below:

```
const some_function = (newDates: {startDate, endDate}) => {
    if (endDate !== null) {
        updateStartEnd(endDate, startDate);
    } else {
        updateStartEnd(endDate, startDate); //here i dont want to pass startDate as it will not need to check for if condition in the updateStartEnd.
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass optional parameters while omitting some other optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734509/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-while-omitting-some-other-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using typescript, you can set default parameters. Also, in this approach as you will always get a `moment` object, `&& newStartDate` becomes a redundant check and can be removed

```js
const updateStartEnd = (newEndDate: moment = moment(), newStartDate: moment = moment()) => {
  if (prevDate && newStartDate.isBefore(prevDate, 'd')) {
    setEndDate(newStartDate);
  } else {
    setEndDate(newEndDate);
  }
};
```

You can even make the args as optional parameter but then you will have to add logic to validate for `undefined`

```js
const updateStartEnd = (newEndDate?: moment, newStartDate?: moment) => {
  if (prevDate && newStartDate && newStartDate.isBefore(prevDate, 'd')) {
    setEndDate(newStartDate);
  } else if(!!newEndDate) {
    setEndDate(newEndDate);
  }
};
```

Also, since you are dealing with dates and you are expecting it to be of type `moment`, its better to use `moment` as type instead of any. That way if I call the fuinction:

```
updateStartEnd(true, true)
```

it would validate and throw error in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make the parameters optional in `updateStartEnd`. Then you need to handle inside `updateStartEnd` when both of these parameters are undefined

```
const updateStartEnd = (newEndDate?: any, newStartDate?: any) => {
    // rest of the code
};
```