# In Typescript, how can you make a prop optional depending on the a generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an type with props that can be optional depending on a generic type:

```
type MyType<R extends Record<string, string> | undefined, A extends string[] | undefined> = {
  record: R
  array: A
}
```

I have a function that takes a `MyType` object

```
const myFunction = <R extends Record<string, string> | undefined, A extends string[] | undefined>(myObject: MyType<R, A>)=>{
  // ... //
}
```

I want to be able to call `myFunction` and omit a `record` in the props if `R` is undefined, for example

```
const record = getTheRecord() // Assuming getTheRecord() returns a undefined here
const array = ['a']
myFunction<undefined, string[]>({
  array
})
```

How can I make some props optional depending on a generic type?

Comment: And what if `A` undefined? Please provide all restrictions

Comment: If `A` is undefined, then the array property should be optional, just like record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67630189/6592293

It seems to be working!

```
type UndefinedToOptional<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
  (x: undefined extends T[K] ? { [P in K]?: T[K] } : { [P in K]: T[K] }) => void
}[keyof T] extends (x: infer I) => void ?
  I extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never : never

type MyType<R extends Record<string, string> | undefined, A extends string[] | undefined> = {
  record: R
  array: A
}

const myFunction = <R extends Record<string, string> | undefined, A extends string[] | undefined>(myObject: UndefinedToOptional<MyType<R, A>>)=>{
  // ... //
}

const array = ['a']
myFunction<undefined, string[]>({
  array
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend `undefined` in the `extend` clause to achieve what you're looking for. If you want to allow "either Record or undefined", where `undefined` is not explicitly assigned, you can do so using a partial type:

```
type MyType<R extends Record<string, string>, A extends string[]> = {
  record?: R
  array?: A
}

const myFunction = <R extends Record<string, string>, A extends string[]>(myObject: MyType<R, A>)=>{
  // ... //
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to call `myFunction` with `R` as undefined as so: `myFunction<undefined, string[]>({ array: [] })`

Comment: I think this is a good answer, and if there's a requirement that you need to manually specify the `R` type argument as `undefined`, it should be written explicitly into the question (right now I don't see any example there where the type argument is manually specified).  I certainly wouldn't want to penalize someone for failing to guess unstated requirements.  Anyway, if you want `| undefined` in there, you can [certainly do that](https://tsplay.dev/w2pb8m).  I'd recommend that OP accepts this answer after editing the question and after the answer is edited to add `| undefined` to match.

Comment: The answer simply added `?` to the prop. My question was how to make a prop conditionally optional. `record` needs to be requred if `R` does not extend `undefined`